# The scope of loading a sub activity on onCreate()

Tags: java, android

I just need some information regarding the scope of execution. On my

Answer (score 3):

To understand what is happening you need to know the [Activity lifecycle](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle)

[image]

As you can see, when the app is launched, the first thing that's going to run is your `onCreate()` in this case, `onCreate()` has a method that inflates the view of your Activity, that method is called [setContentView()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#setContentView(android.view.View)).

so, if you execute your code below setContentView, it will first inflate the view of MainActivity or the class you are in, and then just go to your other Activity.

If you want to start your Activity right when your app launches, just move your `startActivity(...)` above `setContentView()` in your `onCreate()`, but it will be better to do this in your manifest rather than just using a class to open another one.

To launch your WelcomeActivity just do this in your Manifest

```
<activity
            android:name=".WelcomeActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="sensorLandscape">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="sensorLandscape"/>
        <activity
```

So this

```
 <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>

                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
                </intent-filter>
```

will define that WelcomeActivity executes first, then in WelcomeActivity do an intent to your MainActivity

Comment: My test activity is an OnBoarding activity that I need to do launch once. Starting the activity above or below seContetView() does not make a difference visually. I have no idea how to works in the background, though. It is not making much sense to me. Thanks for trying to explain.

Comment: So, you are executing your activity in order to run some code in the background ?

Comment: No, I want to show new users a welcoming screen. I want to only launch the activity with the welcoming onBoarding only if the user did not see it before. I cannot show the onBoarding welcoming screen without creating an activity for it according to the documentation.

Comment: yes, you need to create an Activity, lets say welcomeActivity.class, then go to your manifest and where it hast the intent-filter Launch (thats maybe the MainActivity) you change that MainActivity with your welcomeActivity.class, and MainActivity will be just an <activity></> in your manifest

Answer (score 0):

Rather than load another activity within an activity, perhaps you should consider using a Fragment which are platform-defined modular sections of an activity with its own lifecycle and optional user-interface. See this for more info: https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/fragment-ui

My advice would be to use support Fragments within your activity rather than another activity.

Comment: My test activity is an OnBoarding activity that I need to do launch once. That is why I have put it into a new activity, to load it once and forget it after that without impacting the performance of the app.